# jquery animate() toggle without hiding the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggleclass

Is there a way to toggle a single CSS property using the animate() function without hiding it?
Something like this;

```
$(".block").animate({ 'border-width': 'toggle' }, 1000);
```

I cannot use the toggleClass(), addClass() or removeClass(). The reason for this is that it has an unwanted effect on the size of the element that is animated (see JSFiddle).

[You can find a JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/danied/uabr42a0/)

What I can think of is this;

```
if(parseInt($(".block").css('border-width'))) {
    $(".block").animate({ 'border-width': '0'});
}
else {
    $(".block").animate({ 'border-width': '100px'});
}
```

..Or something like this by adding a class to the element. But I would prefer not to use an if statement. I wonder if this is possible in a single line of code. Feels like it should be.

Comment: I don't see any scrollbar

Comment: You need to click the red element first and then the green element. Like you can see in the JSFiddle. And it's an IE11 thing. In Chrome it works fine.

Comment: I know but nothing happens there is no scrollbar ... Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this, in your css:

```
.block1,
.block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transition: all, 1s;
}
.no-border-top {
    border-top-width: 0;
}
```

then simply toggle no-border-top class, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uabr42a0/43/)

Comment: Great! That did it, and without the weird side effects in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to define toggle effect:

```
var currentBorderW = 0;
$('.block1').on('click', function(){
    var nextBorderW = parseInt($(this).css('border-width'));

    $(this).animate({ 'border-width': currentBorderW + 'px' }, 1000);

    currentBorderW = nextBorderW;
});
```

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7n4grx6z/11/)

Comment: Looks like a good solution, except that this also does not work in IE11... :-S

Comment: @Danielle than change on event to click or use on with document selector

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
$('.block1').on('click', function(){
  $(this).animate({ 'border-width': '-=100px' }, 1000);
});

$('.block2').on('click', function(){
  $(this).children().first().show();
  $(this).toggleClass('borderTop', 1000);
});
```

[JS Fiddle for this code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uabr42a0/46/)
Everything else is the same: your CSS, HTML, etc.  I only changed the property `border-width` to have a value of `-= 100px`.

I used the `-=` operator, per the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

**EDIT**: To make it slide back in again, see [this example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uabr42a0/59/)

```
(function(){
  var clickCount=0;
  $('.block1').click(function(){
  if (clickCount%2==0) {
    $(this).animate({ 'border-width': '-=100px' }, 1000);
  }
  else {
   $(this).animate({ 'border-width': '+=100px' }, 1000); 
  }
  clickCount++;
  });
})();

$('.block2').on('click', function(){
  $(this).children().first().show();
  $(this).toggleClass('borderTop', 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it to also slide out again... to toggle.

Comment: @Danielle - I've updated the example to have it slide in/out again, so it "toggles."